# Dice class, number of sides

Tags: python

I have created a class Dice where I have a function `roll_die` that rolls a dice, and a function `roll_dice` that rolls n number of dices. From this the program present the sum from the die or dices.

I have now tried to add a constructor that allows us to set `number_of sides` to also be able to determine the number of sides on the die or dice, the sides can be 4,6,8,12 or 20, if it is not specified how many sides it should be automatically continued with a six-sided dice.

But I still get an error message `TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'sides'` when the number of pages is not specified, what did I do wrong?

```py
class Dice:
    
    def __init__(self, sides):
        self.sides = sides
        self.value = random.randint(1, self.sides)
    
    def roll_die(self, sides):
        return random.randint(1,sides)
    
    def roll_dice(self,n): 
        sum = 0
        for i in range(n):
            sum += self.roll_die()
        return sum

    def number_of_dice(self, sides):
        if sides == None:
            sides = 6
        
        elif sides not in (4,6,8,12,20):
            print('The dice can only be of size 4,6,8,12 or 20')
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: I have no idea what "when the number of pages is not specified" is supposed to mean. There's nothing about "pages" either in your description of the problem, or in your code.

Comment: "if it is not specified how many sides it should be automatically continued with a six-sided dice." Is there something in your code that's intended to make that happen? Where is the code for that? How is it supposed to work?

Comment: I think it is better if you try to follow a tutorial and make sure you understand someone else's designs, first.

Comment: There is no point in passing `sides` to `roll_die` - you want to use `self.sides`. It's also not clear what the purpose of `self.value` is.

Answer (score 2):

I'd write your class like this

```py
class Dice:
    def __init__(self, sides=6):
        if sides not in (4,6,8,12,20):
            raise Exception("Invalid value for sides. Use one of following: 4, 6, 8, 12, 20")
        self.sides = sides

    def roll_dice(self):
        return random.randint(1,self.sides)
     
    def roll_dices(self, n): 
        sum = 0
        for _ in range(n):
            sum += self.roll_dice()
        return sum
```

I didn't get what you used method `number_of_dice` for, so I didn't add it. But that value check is included in constructor.

And I renamed method roll_die to roll_dice and method for rolling multiple times to roll_dices. It felt better.

Comment: Hmm.. Now I am unsure about word dice.... is its plurar dice or dices? I am not a native English speaker, so please forgive my broken English.

Comment: In some (most? mine anyway) forms of English, "dice" is the plural, and "die" is singular. Some variants do use dice as singular too, so I'm not sure any one spelling will work for everyone.

Comment: Ok, learning daily. If we use die as a singular then class name should probably be Die not Dice.

Answer (score 1):

You should give it a default value in your constructor, which it will take when the argument is not supplied.

```
def __init__(self, sides=6):
    self.sides = sides
    self.value = random.randint(1, self.sides)
```

d = Dice(20) will return an instance of Dice with 20 sides
d = Dice() will return an instance of Dice with 6 sides, which is the default.

Comment: I did this and still got the same, error. How can this be?

Comment: It can't. But you have another error. In `roll_dice` you call `self.roll_die()`. You're missing the parameter `sides` here.

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: It only works when I write `def roll_die(self, sides=6):`but then I also have to write `d=Dice(20)` and `print(d.roll_die(20))`?

Comment: @quamrana I am sorry, but I do not know how to find the error traceback. I will try to find out how and post it.

Comment: You've already quote part of it: `TypeError: ... `. Just run the code again and you will get the error.